# my nodejs backend returns null but still register in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, android-studio, null

i created two endpoint one to get the createorder and the other to update the order so as to generate orderId and detail about the order but the createorder keep returning null but still registrating in  the database .here is the code

```
router.post('/createOrder', function (req, res, next) {
if (req.body.key == API_KEY) {

    var order_phone = req.body.orderPhone
    var order_name = req.body.orderName
    var order_address = req.body.orderAddress
    var order_date = moment(req.body.orderDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    var restaurant_id = req.body.restaurantId
    var transaction_id = req.body.transactionId
    var cod = (req.body.cod == "true")
    var total_price = req.body.totalPrice
    var num_of_item = req.body.numOfItem
    var order_fbid = req.body.orderFBID




    if (order_fbid != null) {
        req.getConnection(function (error, conn) {
            conn.query('INSERT INTO `Order`(OrderFBID,OrderPhone,OrderName,OrderAddress,OrderStatus,OrderDate,RestaurantId,'
                + 'TransactionId,COD,TotalPrice,NumOfItem) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [order_fbid, order_phone, order_name, order_address, 0, order_date, restaurant_id, transaction_id, cod, total_price, num_of_item], function (err, rows, fields) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500)
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: err.message }))
                    }
                    else {
                        conn.query('SELECT OrderId as OrderNumber FROM `Order` WHERE OrderFBID=? AND NumOfItem > 0 '
                            + 'ORDER BY orderNumber DESC LIMIT 1', [order_fbid], function (err, rows, fields) {

                                if (err) {
                                    res.status(500)
                                    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: err.message }))
                                }
                                else {
                                    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, result: rows }))
                                }
                            })

                    }
                })
        })
    }
    else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Missing orderFBID body  marfe" }))
    }
}
else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Wrong api key marfe" }))
}
```

})

so after much efforts trying to get my code working i decided to change the json to success true

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, result: rows }))
```

but then i got UPDATEDORDER HTTP 500 Internal server errors

here is the updateorder

```
router.post('/updateOrder', function (req, res, next) {
if (req.body.key == API_KEY) {

    var order_id = req.body.orderId
    var order_detail

    try {
        order_detail = JSON.parse(req.body.orderDetail)
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(500)
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: err.message }))
    }

    if (order_detail != null && order_id != null) {

        var data_insert = []
        for (i = 0; i < order_detail.length; i++) {
            data_insert[i] = [
                parseInt(order_id),
                order_detail[i]["foodId"],
                order_detail[i]["foodQuantity"],
                order_detail[i]["foodPrice"],
                0, // discount
                order_detail[i]["foodSize"],
                order_detail[i]["foodAddon"],
                parseFloat(order_detail[i]["foodExtraPrice"])
            ]
        }
        req.getConnection(function (error, conn) {
            conn.query('INSERT INTO OrderDetail(OrderId,ItemId,Quantity,Price,Discount,Size,Addon,ExtraPrice) VALUES(?)', data_insert, function (err, rows, fields) {

                if (err) {
                    res.status(500)
                    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: err.message }))
                }
                else {
                    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, message: "update success" }))

                }
            })
        })
    }
    else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Missing orderID body  marfe" }))
    }
}
else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Wrong api key marfe" }))
}
```

})

here is the order detail

```
router.get('/orderDetail', function (req, res, next) {
if (req.query.key == API_KEY) {
    req.getConnection(function (error, conn) {
        var order_id = req.query.orderId
        if (order_id != null) {
            conn.query('SELECT orderId,itemId,quantity,discount,extraPrice,size,addOn FROM OrderDetail WHERE orderId=?', [order_id], function (err, rows, fields) {

                if (err) {
                    res.status(500)
                    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: err.message }))
                }
                else {
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, result: rows }))
                    }
                    else {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Empty" }))
                    }
                }
            })

        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Missing orderId in query" }))
        }

    })
}
else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Wrong orderFBID key marfe" }))
}
```

})

Comment: Your post handler finishes executing before the DB insert happens. Unrelated, but that's some pretty deep nesting you have going on there; at the very least I'd invert all of the guard clauses and flatten things out.

Comment: "Your post handler finishes executing before the DB insert " i don't understand this can you help me break it down a bit

Comment: i posted the orderdetail sir

Comment: What exactly is being returned as null? is it `rows`? if yes, then the issue is in the query...try running that query in the db first and see if it returns data, if it does then we need to know what field is being returned as null

Comment: it is the create order that's returning null but still registrating in the database